Using .navigationDestination(for:destination:) with multiple layers of navigation
I have a SwiftUI application with a main page (ContentView) which contains a link to a second page (OtherView) of multiple items inside a List. These items are NavigationLinks. When I use .navigationDestination(for:destination:) inside this List, the link opens to a copy of the view and causes the following error:

A navigationDestination for "MyCustomType" was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used.

Making OtherView the root view of the NavigationStack by removing the link the link around it (like in Variant A) fixes the problem, but then I couldn't use a main page. I would like to avoid using an enum for routes, because that wouldn't work very well for navigation with multiple layers.
(EDIT: as far as I can tell.
I would accept a solution with enums as long as I can have a navigationDestination that contains a list with navigationDestinations. I assume this isn't considered quite the same issue, so I should probably make a separate question?)
This is my code:
// OtherView.swift

struct OtherView: View {
    let dummyItems: [MyCustomType] = [
        .init(/* something 1 */),
        .init(/* something 2 */),
        .init(/* something 3 */)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(dummyItems, id: \.id) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    Text(item.description)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// ContentView.swift

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            // Variant A (works):
            OtherView()
                .navigationDestination(for: MyCustomType.self) { Text($0.description) }
            
            // Variant B (doesn't work):
            NavigationLink("Some Link") {
                OtherView()
                    .navigationDestination(for: MyCustomType.self) { Text($0.description) }
            }
        }
    }
}

(Variant B causes the above mentioned issues while Variant A works as expected)
Note: Yes, I have seen a few other people mention similar issues around here, but none of their solutions worked for me.
EDIT: I don't see how navigationDestination was declared earlier on the stack would solve my problem (I'm quite possibly just missing something) as it seems to be about using navigationDestination(isPresented:_:) in combination with navigationDestination(for:_:).
EDIT: I replaced usages of String with MyCustomType to clarify that I'm not using Strings as a bad enum replacement.

Enum is the way to go, hardcoded Strings are generally considered code smell

try using NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {...}, see: Manage-navigation-state

Why don't you want to use enums? What does "because that wouldn't work very well for navigation with multiple layers" mean? You can keep the strings, but the navigation link in ContentView should have a non-String value. It doesn't have to be enums if you don't like enums, any other type would work, though I would not recommend that. Just use an enum.

@loremipsum I'm not using Strings here as a replacement for an enum, I just needed a MRE, so I used a String instead of a custom type.

@workingdogsupportUkraine would that mean replacing NavigationLinks with Buttons that change the path?

No you don't have to use a Button, NavigationLink(...value:...) is fine.
You can pass the navigationPath to the .navigationDestination view, eg
SomeView(path: $navigationPath, item: item)
